# Can’t input my password to log into MacOS because my computer acts as if Shift is always pressed

Tags: macos, keyboard, login-screen

This just started today and it’s been very concerning. When I went to log into my MacBook Pro, my password was rejected the first three times I entered it. When going to the recovery assistant and entering my Apple ID , I realized that I was typing in only capitals without caps lock being on (and I can’t type numbers, either, instead the symbols attached to them). I suspect that this effect is extending to the login screen password entry. It seems that my Mac thinks that the Shift key is always being pressed, and I can’t disable it in order to type my password (which has lowercase letters and numbers in it).

After reading the response to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/381001/my-macbook-pro-is-acting-as-if-the-shift-key-were-pressed-when-it-absolutely-isn) I tried to reset NVRAM and PRAM, but my laptop didn’t do anything even though I have an Intel Mac (it booted up as if I hadn’t held command + option + r + p). Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!!

Comment: Have you got a USB or Bluetooth keyboard? For more see https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/354066/237

Comment: Your key is physically stuck.  No amount of resetting NVRAM will fix a physical problem.  You need to get it fixed.